# Extjs4 disable "Delete" button by default but when select any row enable the button

Tags: button, extjs4, cls

I have two "delete" button on top of a grid, one is red another is gray.
When no row selected, the button is the gray one. Otherwise, it shows the red one.
How to do that using Extjs4?

Comment: Can you show your code here? It is much easier to start from some code than just explaining text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen **select** event of grid - hide gray, show red. After reloading grid, or if grid store becomes empty - do the opposite. But if think you must use one button with css styles for disabled/enabled controls and **setDisabled** method. Cause logically it's two states of the one button.